# How to read Geotiff tags and pixel per pixel values using GDAL C#

Tags: c#, gdal, geotiff-tiff, srtm

I'm new here and I'm new at programing with GDAL C#.

My question is how I can get the value of SRTM GEOTIFF pixel to compare with it's neighbors, and how can I get the values of Geotiff tags.

Comment: With the Python bindings, I would read the GeoTiff pixel values into a numpy array.  Is there equivalent large array access in C#?

Comment: Hi DavidF, probably it will work, but in my program I need to use a mask 3x3 who will use to get the image pixels values to compare (or it is what I'm thinking for my porpose).

Answer (score 2):

You have two questions:

1. Reading pixel data from the Geotiff:
   Here you find a [C# GDAL Read Raster Code Sample](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/csharp/apps/GDALRead.cs).
   The final reading method is called **Band.ReadRaster**!
2. Reading Geotiff-Tags:
   Depends which Tags you mean...

   - If you want to read the GeoTransform-Parameters (Georeference-Info), you would do that with the method **Dataset.GetGeoTransform**.
   - If you want to read the Projection-Parameters, you would do that with **Dataset.GetProjectionRef**.
   - If you want to read any other Geotiff Tags, forget GDAL and use any other lib, like [LibTiff.Net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/).